# MarkLogic - xdmp:Spawn Privilege for trigger

Tags: triggers, permissions, marklogic, privileges

I am trying to trigger a process on the backend when data gets changed.

Here is a working trigger that I am currently using.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace trgr="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/triggers" 
    at "/MarkLogic/triggers.xqy";


if (xdmp:database() eq xdmp:database("nbcu-test-ml-triggers")) 
   then ()
   else fn:error((), 'NOTTRIGGERSDB', xdmp:database()) ,
trgr:create-trigger(
     "typeahead_modify", 
     "Update Typeahead Document",
     trgr:trigger-data-event(trgr:directory-scope("/triplestore/", "1"), trgr:document-content("modify"),     trgr:post-commit()),
     trgr:trigger-module(
         xdmp:database("nbcu-test-ml-modules"), 
         "/ext/", 
         "sample-trigger.xqy"),
     fn:true(), 
     xdmp:default-permissions(),
     fn:true() )
```

However at the end of the module it is triggering, I would like to call an xdmp:spawn-function in order to do some asynchronous processing.

I am pretty new to Permission management, but I tried adding to the set of permissions a `xdmp:privilege`, but that didn't work.

Can someone please help to advise how to add `xdmp:Spawn execute` privilege to this trigger?

Thanks

Edit: I use mlgradle to deploy the /ext/sample-trigger.xqy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of the user running the trigger is the user that caused the insert/update/delete/property-change on the document. The only exception to this rule is the database online event in which you actually define a user.

Therefore, the xdmp:spawn privilege must be attached to a role that is attached (directly or indirectly) to the user described above.

To troubleshoot, you could add xdm:log(xdmp:get-current-user()) to the trigger module to make sure you understand the user being used to invoke the code. Then add the xdmp:spawn privilege to one of the roles of that user.

Comment: `get-current-user()` helped me realize I was not running the user I thought I was... Thanks for the guidance!

Comment: No Problem. Glad it helped!